# Get the smallest side of a user device screen size JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen

I want to get user device *display* size with `screen.width` and `screen.height` on page load (for example: iPhone 7, 375x667px), then I need to compare these two sizes and use the smallest size (375px) to apply it to an element with `CSS` function.

```
function() {
  var ww = screen.width;
  var wh = screen.height;   
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript so don't know how to do the second part, comparison and further manipulation.

How can it be done?

Comment: You can use an operator to check which of the two is higher. Please show us what you have tried so far and we'll help you from there.

Comment: Why would you not want to use `if`...? That's exactly what you need

Comment: iOS, Android (and other platform) don't work with screen.width/height the same way, most of them are not change it on orientation change @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: So the issue then becomes 'how do I reliably get the screen width/height across devices', not 'how do I compare values without an `if` statement'?

Comment: My question is already cross browser, because one side is always smaller then another (no matter on what orientation the device), and I need only this number to further manipulation @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: `var smallest = Math.min(ww, wh)`

Comment: Assuming you only run this code when the page loads have you tried hooking it to an `orientationchange` event as well?

Comment: "*I don't know how to compare without `if`*" - what's wrong with `if`(as asked earlier, but no answered satisfactorily)?  The "operator" is `<` (less than) and you can use the "conditional operator" `?:` - but it's essentially still `if` - `var smallest = ww < wh ? ww : wh;` - so not really sure what you're after.

Comment: Nope, I don't need to, and it can be done without `orientationchange` event as I explained above @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I'm not against `if`, but in common approach I will get the result in the answer below, which I could done by myself, but in the case of that answer I will be depending on orientation change - I don't want that @freedomn-m

Comment: You're depending on the orientation change no matter what logical processes you use. This question seems to have a lot of confusion surrounding... whatever the issue you have is. I suspect you'd get more helpful answers if you had described the problem you want to solve instead of whatever the problems are with your attempted solution.

Comment: The smallest is always the smallest regardless of orientation. 375x667 or 667x375 is still 375.  None of the 3 provided options to get 375 relies on the orientation or on an orientation change.  You've been provided with how to get that value, which is what the question asks (how to get 375).

Comment: Are there two people asking this question?  "I don't know how to make the comparison" "I only need this number for further manipulation" then "I could do by myself".   Still no idea what you're actually asking!

Comment: If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you @CalvinNunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments by many people, we can't understant why not to use `if`.

You could have used conditional operators: `?` and `:`, but it is in essentially an `if`.

You can also make use of the `Math` library with `min()` or `max()` functions to get the smallest or highest value of some values (can be used for arrays also, but it is not the case here). 
The usage: `Math.min(value1, value2)`

Example:

```js
var ww = 100;
var wv = 120;
var smallest = Math.min(ww,wv);
console.log(smallest)
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min

To finish, `Math.min()` or `max()` also uses `if` in the internal code...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using jquery,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var smallest;
        var winwid = $(window).width();
        var winheight = $(window).height();
        if(winwid < winheight ){
            smallest = winwid;
            alert('Width is smaller than height: '+winwid);
        }
        else {
            smallest = winheight;
            alert('Height is smaller than width: '+winheight);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```